# Material-UI Style Override?

Tags: material-ui, jss

I'm updating my app from Material-UI v1 to v2. I'm trying to use a style override to set the color of a selected `<BottomNavigationAction>` element.

```
const styles = {
    bottomNavStyle: {
        position: 'fixed',
        left: '0px',
        bottom: '0px',
        height: '50px',
        width: '100%',
        zIndex: '100'
    },
    '&$selected': {
        color: "#00bcd4"  //<==trying to add this color to selected items
    },
};


class bottom_nav extends Component {
    state = {
        selectedIndex: -1,
    };

    handleChange = (event, value) => {
        this.setState({value});
    };


    render() {
        const { classes } = this.props;

        return (
            <Paper className={classes.bottomNavStyle}>
                <BottomNavigation
                    value={this.props.selectedBottomNavIndex}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    showLabels
                 >
                    <BottomNavigationAction
                        label="Appointments"
                        icon={theApptsIcon}
                    />
                    <BottomNavigationAction
                        label="Contacts"
                        icon={theEmailIcon}
                    />
                    <BottomNavigationAction
                        label="Video Call"
                        icon={theVideoCall}
                    />
                </BottomNavigation>
            </Paper>
        );
    }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(bottom_nav);
```

But, this does not do anything to the color of `selected` items.

I've read the Material-UI docs on CSS in JS and JSS, but haven't quite gotten it yet. What is the correct syntax for this?

**UPDATE**

Based on a response to this thread I've tried this:

```
const styles = {
    bottomNavStyle: {
        position: 'fixed',
        left: '0px',
        bottom: '0px',
        height: '50px',
        width: '100%',
        zIndex: '100'
    },
    actionItemStyle: {
        '&$selected': {
            color: "#00bcd4 !important"
        },
    },
}
```

[.....]

```
    return (
        <Paper className={classes.bottomNavStyle}>
            <BottomNavigation
                value={this.props.selectedBottomNavIndex}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                showLabels
            >
                <BottomNavigationAction
                    label="Appointments"
                    icon={theApptsIcon}
                    className={classes.actionItemStyle}
                />
                <BottomNavigationAction
                    label="Contacts"
                    icon={theEmailIcon}
                    className={classes.actionItemStyle}
                />
                <BottomNavigationAction
                    label="Video Call"
                    icon={theVideoCall}
                    className={classes.actionItemStyle}
                />
            </BottomNavigation>
        </Paper>
    );
}
```

...but have not yet gotten the new color to appear on the web page.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your updated solution looks good, there are just a few small changes...

1. You need to include an empty `.selected` class in your styles rules.

```js
const styles = {
  // Root styles for `BottomNavigationAction` component
  actionItemStyles: {
    "&$selected": {
      color: "red"
    }
  },
  // This is required for the '&$selected' selector to work
  selected: {}
};
```

2. You need to pass `classes={{selected: classes.selected}}` to `BottomNavigationAction`. This is required for the `'&$selected'` selector to work.

```js
<BottomNavigation
  value={value}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  className={classes.root}
>
  <BottomNavigationAction
    classes={{
      root: classes.actionItemStyles,
      selected: classes.selected
    }}
    label="Recents"
    value="recents"
    icon={<RestoreIcon />}
  />
</BottomNavigation>
```

**Live Example:**

[image: Edit Material UI ButtonNavigationAction styles]

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things I would like to suggest.

1) Write the name of the component with first letter capitalized since it is not treated the same way if it is named with small first letter and with capitalized.

2) If there is no other way for your cs rule to be applied, if it is overridden always because of some css specificity, use !iportant at the end of the rule.

3) Try this type of nesting of css in jss:

```
const styles = {
    bottomNavStyle: {
        position: 'fixed',
        left: '0px',
        bottom: '0px',
        height: '50px',
        width: '100%',
        zIndex: '100',
        '&:selected': {
           color: "#00bcd4"
        },
    },
};
```