# Material-ui Override StepLabel nested property

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to override the marginTop: 16 property that occurs in this implementation of StepLabel:

```
  label: {
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
    '&$active': {
      color: theme.palette.text.primary,
      fontWeight: 500,
    },
    '&$completed': {
      color: theme.palette.text.primary,
      fontWeight: 500,
    },
    '&$alternativeLabel': {
      textAlign: 'center',
      marginTop: 16,
    },
    '&$error': {
      color: theme.palette.error.main,
    },
  },
```

So that I get this as the desired outcome: 
[image]

But I cannot for the life of me figure out how.... here's my implementation:

```
  <StepLabel
         classes={{
            root: classes.root,
            labelContainer: classes.labelContainer,
            label: classes.myLabel
         }}
       >
         {this.state.labels[label - 1]}
  </StepLabel>
```

*Here's the classes:*

```
    const styles = theme => ({
      root: {
        marginTop: 0,
        padding: 0,
        "& $alternativeLabel": {
          marginTop: 0
        }
      },
      labelContainer: {
        backgroundColor: "green",
        marginTop: 0,
        "& $alternativeLabel": {
          marginTop: 0
        }
      },
      myLabel: {
        backgroundColor: "red",
        marginTop: 0,
        "& $alternativeLabel": {
          marginTop: 0
        }
      },
  });
```

The result - the marginTop DOES NOT get overridden. :(

[image]

Further information - the property that I want to override: 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

seems like the way to do it is like this - credit to this answer [Material-UI Style Override?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52602392/material-ui-style-override)

Put an empty alternativeLabel: {} in, so that the property &$alternativeLabel is overridden:

```
const styles = theme => ({
      labelContainer: {
        "& $alternativeLabel": {
          marginTop: 0
        }
      },
      alternativeLabel: {}, 
});
```

and then call it like this in your component:

```
        <StepLabel
          classes={{
            alternativeLabel: classes.alternativeLabel,
            labelContainer: classes.labelContainer
          }}
        >
```